# VSC - Edit Open/Closing Tag Background Color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

How can I change the background color of a matching HTML opening and closing tag on visual studio code?

Webstorm - Jetbrains changes the background of matching tags accordingly.
[image]

On VSC, All I want is to change the background color of the matching tag:
[image]

on VSC. I've tried:

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorBracketMatch.border": "#00d16e",
        "editorBracketMatch.background": "#fe6659",

    }
```

However nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure why but this colorCustomization works for me:

```
"editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#f00",
```

Seems poorly named but works.

Answer (score 0):

For Webstorm - Jetbrains try this:

File/Setting/Editor/Color Scheme/General/Code/Identifier under caret

Just change background color value.

Comment: What editor is that?  The question is about vscode.